Click on 'arrow' in Merdaid JS Chart
I have an app that renders Mermaid JS Flowcharts.
For example something like this:
  flowchart TD
    
    p1 -->|10.000| p2
    p2 -->|10.000| p3
    p1 -->|45| p3
    p3 -->|9888| p4
    p3 -->|122| p2

This is rendered as a list of edgeLabels:
<g class="edgeLabels"><g class="edgeLabel" transform="translate(71.03515625, 68.5)">
<g class="label" transform="translate(-24.5703125, -9.5)">
<foreignObject width="49.140625" height="19"><div style="color: green; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="edgeLabel" style="color:green;">10.000</span></div></foreignObject>
</g>
</g>
<g class="edgeLabel" transform="translate(24.5703125, 171.5)"><g class="label" ...

What would be the best way to implement an onclick, so that I know which edge is clicked?
So for example, I'd like to know if a user clicked the first 10.000, that it was the p1->p2 edge.

I will go ahead and add this as an answer since it might get too big for a comment.
Completely untested-
An option is to have function that will get a reference to each path/edge, and assign a click handler to get the id.
Use a selector like const edgeContainer = document.querySelector('#graph-div g.edgePaths') as HTMLElement;
Then loop through each path to assign the click handler.
In the click handler you could then query the element to get the id, which would look like L-p1-p2-0 for your example.
You can also reference the edgeLabel by selecting the element with data-id="L-p1-p2-0


Thanks, but the issue is that the labels don't contain the data-id information that the paths do.
